# Mobile app -> how to fecth http requests?

Tags: android, ios, http, web, soap

Is there a way to catch http requests like we do in devTools in chrome in the mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chucker library for the same .

Add these two lines in your project build.gradle file

```
  debugImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:3.5.2"
  releaseImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2"
```

Add Java 8 support

```
android {
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  // For Kotlin projects add also this line
  kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

In your retrofit add a chucker interceptor like so

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(ChuckerInterceptor(context))
                .build()
```

[More Info](https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker)

Answer (score 0):

A program I use professionally is Charles, it’s quite archaic but it’s cheap and useful. You need to install some certificates but after that you can sniff requests just like you do in Chrome